# Route is not used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller which has an action that looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Edit(long? page)
```

I have defined the following routing in `UseEndpoints` in my `Startup` class

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "Area",
pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{page?}");
```

However the route is not picked up an matched to the controller action.
When I change the routing to this

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "Area",
pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

The routing is working, but obviously the `page` parameter of the method is `null`, because the routing would expect an `id` parameter.

is there any special case for an `id` parameter that I have missed, that I need to add so my routing with the `page` parameter will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [reserved words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reserved-routing-names) that can't be used as route segments or parameter names.

Using `page` as a route parameter is a common error.

Comment: This was actually the problem. Because we introduced Microsoft identity, we needed an MVC builder and tried adding it through `AddRazorPages()` or `AddMvc()`. This was not present in our codebase before. Using `AddControllersWithViews()` instead fixed the problem and gave us the required `MvcBuilder` for `AddMicrosoftIdentityUI()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference

```
 between pattern "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); and 
pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{page?}");
```

since your url will be looking like `...area/controller/edit/12345
and it will be working the same way

```
 for action public IActionResult Edit(long? page)  
and for public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
```

But as mentioned @FeiHan don't use word "page" for routting,  better leave just "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}") or you can select any another name  instead of "id".